# Magento 1.9.2 - Fails to send sales transaction emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.0

I've recently upgraded / patched a Magento store to version 1.9.2 (from 1.9.1 via Magento Connect). It runs on a Centos server using PHP 5.5.26. Everything seems to work fine except I'm not getting any sales transaction emails from the store.

I've verified that php mail can send email from the server via a small php script invoked via browser. And this test used the same email from and to addresses used by sales transaction emails.

I can see in the exception log that the cron task is running, but it is generating an exception that ends with:

> "exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in ...lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137".

I've researched this error, but have not found anything leading to a solution.

I've verified the sales transaction emails are queued in the database (`core_email_queue` table) just waiting for the cron task to initiate sending.

I've even tried setting up a free Mandrill account and installed the MageMonkey extension. But, that is not sending emails either.

Still looking for a solution. Any suggestions on where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to apply [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78587/magento-1-9-2-not-sending-new-order-confirmation-emails). its work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 1.9.2 not sending new order confirmation emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78587/magento-1-9-2-not-sending-new-order-confirmation-emails)

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem also running Centos and got it to work by adjusting the rights of my cron.sh in the root-catalog of the webserver. It seems the Magento update messed it up. If you got a backup from when it was working take a look and adjust that way - else I found that making it:
read, write, executable from apache and read and executable from the rest made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.